# expected ORM mapped attribute for loader strategy argument Python SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I have some problem after update to SQLAlchemy 2.0

```
self.selected_fields = ['id', 'username', ...]
```

This field used for select only used in GraphQL query fields.

```
self.sql = select(model).options(load_only(*self.selected_fields))
```

I paste list of str to load_only, but i have error.

```
raise exc.NoInspectionAvailable(
sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable: No inspection system is available for object of type <class 'str'>
self.sql = select(model).options(load_only(*self.selected_fields))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategy_options.py", line 2398, in load_only
_, lead_element, _ = _parse_attr_argument(attrs[0])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategy_options.py", line 2347, in _parse_attr_argumentraise sa_exc.ArgumentError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: expected ORM mapped attribute for loader strategy argument
```

What i need to do for translate str columns to ORM columns?

I read a lot of documentation and try to search something at Google, but i cant... Help please

Comment: Does `[getattr(ModelClass, f) for f in self.selected_fields]` work ?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks, it solved my problem. Forgot about setattr / getattr :)